# django how to change __str__ label by user status?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to change select option's label by user status.

my model is

```
class BookCategory(model):
    label_1 = char
    label_2 = char

    def __unicode__(self):
        #something here?

class Book(model):
    name = char
    categoey = models.Foreignkey(BookCategory)
```

BookCategory is used in createview for new book, and the page has modelform, textinput for book.name and choices for book.catgory.

My goal is
if user type==1:
=>display category's label_1

if user type==2:
=>display category's label_2

I know  "__unicode__" can display instance's value, but I want to know change its field by user's status.

Anyone knows the solution?

add:
my view and modelform are so simple.

view is

```
class CreateBook(CreateView):
  template_name = "template.html"
  model = Book
  form_class = BookForm
  success_url = "success_url"

  def form_valid(self, form):
      if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
```

and form is

```
class LessonForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('name',
                  'category',
        )
        widgets = {
              'name': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'text_box'}),
              'category': forms.Textinput(attrs={'class': 'select_box'}),
        }
```

Comment: You can't do this in the `__unicode__` method, because you don't have access to the `request`. If you show your view and form, you might be able to change them to do what you want.

Comment: @Alasdair thank you for your advice! I add my view and form in my post. Would you tell me how to pass "request" to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) to create two custom models fields. Override `label_from_instance` to customize how you want the object to be displayed in the form.

```
class Type1CategoryField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.label1

class Type2CategoryField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.label1
```

Then change your form so that it takes `user` as a keyword argument, and change the category field to use the appropriate model choice field.

```
class LessonForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('name',
                  'category',
        )
        widgets = {
              'name': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'text_box'}),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(LessonForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user.user_type == 1:
            self.fields['category'] = Type1CategoryField(queryset=Category.objects.all())
        elif user.user_type == 2:
            self.fields['category'] = Type2CategoryField(queryset=Category.objects.all())
```

It doesn't make sense to use `forms.Textinput` for a choice field, so I removed `category` from your `widgets`.

Finally, modify your view so that it includes the logged-in user in the form kwargs. Use `LoginRequiredMixin` to make sure that only logged-in users can access the view.

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class CreateBook(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = "template.html"
    model = Book
    form_class = BookForm
    success_url = "success_url"

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(CreateBook, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = request.user
```